# How can I handle NameError and AttributeError gracefully in the Mako runtime environment?

Tags: python, templates, template-engine, mako

I've found that trying to access an undefined variable within a Mako template raises a `NameError`, and quite logically so. In some applications, however, it's desirable to fail more gracefully, perhaps substituting the empty string on such errors (`AttributeError` is another candidate). This is the default behavior in the Django template language. Is there a way to get this behavior in Mako?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, turns out that a little more googling [makes it plain](http://markmail.org/message/qxwkijhbz5rdx3dg):

```
import mako.runtime
mako.runtime.UNDEFINED = ''
```

Now undefined variables will produce the empty string.

Reading the source for the original value of UNDEFINED is enlightening:

```
class Undefined(object):
    """Represents an undefined value in a template.

    All template modules have a constant value 
    ``UNDEFINED`` present which is an instance of this
    object.

    """
    def __str__(self):
        raise NameError("Undefined")
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False
```

And there we go. Thanks, Google.

Comment: To be fair, my attempts at Googling this problem were futile as well. Thanks anyway.